# find 2 numbers that multiply to given number using a given ratio

Tags: c#, for-loop, math

I am trying to make a nested for loop where the outer loop and the inner loop do a certain amount of total iterations, but they do not have the same amount of iterations each. Instead, the iterations for each loop should be calculated based on a given ratio and a given total iterations. My function will take in a total amount of iterations, (`M`), and a `ratio`. Based on this, it should calculate how many times the outer loop should iterate and how many times the inner loop should iterate, so that the total iterations equals `M`.

For example, given `ratio = 0.5` and `M = 225`, each loop should iterate the same amount of times (since the ratio is 50%), and the total iterations should equal 225. In this case, each loop should do `15` iterations:

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    ...etc
```

In the context of some code:

```cs
//these will be given as function parameters, but for these purposes they are constant
int M = 225;
double ratio = 0.5;

int outerIterations = //some calculation
int innerIterations = //some other calculation

//the amount of iterations each loop has done
int totalIters = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < outerIterations; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < innerIterations; j++) {
        totalIters++;
        //in here, something is done M times
    }
}
```

In the above example, `totalIters` should equal `200`, `outerIterations` should equal `15`, and `innerIterations` should also equal `15`. This example is very easy, because it is just 50/50 between the two loops (because the ratio is `0.5`). The problem is I dont know how to get the 2 values I need from the ratio and the total iterations.

I have tried:

```
int innerIterations = (int)(M * ratio)
int outerIterations = (int)(M / innerIterations)
//This produces 2 numbers that will multiply to M, but doesn't maintain the correct ratio
```

other than that I have no clue where to begin, because it seems this is a fairly unique problem and none of the google/stackoverflow searches i have done have produced anything relevant.

Overall, the question I'm asking is what calculations I need to perform in order to get these 2 values (`outerIterations` and `innerIterations`), so the the for loops maintain the ratio given, and iterate `M` times.

Comment: I think, you should try asking on https://math.stackexchange.com/ because the problem is purely math.

Comment: I was considering asking on math.stackexchange.com, but I wasn't really sure whether i should because of how i phrased it with the code. Should i post on there too, or delete this and repost on there?

Comment: Well, now you have written it, see if someone answers today. If not, delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to establish what your ratio means.  I'm going to take it to mean the ratio of the outer iterations to the total (outer + inner).

```
outer/(outer + inner) = ratio
outer = ratio(outer + inner)
outer = ratio * outer + ratio * inner
outer - ratio * outer = ratio * inner
outer(1 - ratio) = ratio * inner
outer = ratio/(1 - ratio) * inner
```

We also know the product of outer and inner will be the total iterations

```
outer * inner = total
ratio/(1 - ratio) * inner² = total
inner² = total(1 - ratio)/ratio
inner = √(total(1 - ratio)/ratio)

outer * inner = total
outer = total/inner
```

---

So, that leaves us with the formulas:

```
1) inner = √(total(1 - ratio)/ratio)
2) outer = total/inner
```

In your case:

```
inner = √(225(1 - 0.5)/0.5) = √(225) = 15
outer = 225/15 = 15
```

You'll need to decide how to handle the cases when there isn't an integer solution.